# MySql большое количество Rows examined

Tags: mysql

У меня вопрос к спецам по MySql. В логе медленных запросов есть вот такой запрос:

```
select *
from `orders`
where (
        `id` = 'подольск'
        or `startpoint` like '%подольск%'
        or `endpoint` like '%подольск%'
        or `ic_txt` like '%подольск%'
        or `manager_txt` like '%подольск%'
        or `car_type_text` like '%подольск%'
        or `cargo_type_txt` like '%подольск%'
        or `car_count` like '%подольск%'
        or `dispatcher_txt` like '%подольск%'
        or `start_street` like '%подольск%'
        or `end_street` like '%подольск%'
    )
    and `deleted_at` is null
    and `state_id` not in (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
order by `created_at` desc
limit 25 offset 0
```

Данный запрос возвращает всего три записи.

И `Rows_examined: 114082` что значит обработано 114082 строк.

Если убрать из этого запроса `LIKE` и выбрать количество записей

```
select count(*)
from `orders`
where
    `deleted_at` is null
    and `state_id` not in (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

То мы получим всего 300 штук.

Всего записей в таблице 114105 (на момент выполнения запроса было 114082 видимо). Т.е. перебираются все записи в таблице. Чего, по моему мнению, происходить не должно. Я бы ожидал, будут обработаны всего 300 записей, а остальные отброшены по индексу.

Индексы для полей `deleted_at` и `state_id` присутсвуют.

`EXPLAIN` показывает следующее:

`+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys               |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | orders | index | PRIMARY,deleted_at,state_id |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+-----------------------------+`

`+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| created_at | 4       | NULL |   71 | Using where |
+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+`

Насколько я понимаю, индексу MySql видит, но не считает нужным их использовать.

Есть какие либо идеи?

PS: В EXPLAIN как я вижу показывает обработку всего 71 строки (возможно кеш). Почему тогда в боевом варианте такие вещи происходят?

Comment: Так в запросе же `like` обрабатывает кучу строковых полей не индексов? Что требует полного перебора таблицы.

Comment: Почему, если `where `deleted_at` is null and `state_id` not in (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` оставляет всего 300 записей?

Comment: Я не прям спец по MySQL, поэтому лишь предполагаю. Возможно дело в порядке операций в `where` – сначала же идут `like` по куче не индексных полей. Или наоборот, возможно порядок не важен, если есть операции с не индексными колонками, просто обрабатывается всё. Поэтому для ускорения можно попробовать обернуть фильтр по индексам в подзапрос.

Comment: Ваши LIKE не могут использовать индексы (в принципе не могут, так что не старайтесь оптимизировать созданием индексов, и не спрашивайте об идеях - бесполезно), поэтому сканируется каждая запись таблицы. Если же все LIKE убрать, то оставшиеся условия прекрасно используют индексы.

Comment: @Akina речь про то, что там условие `and`, вторая часть которого оставляет в выборке лишь 300 записей.

Comment: если хз как исправить, то  напишите с подзапросом. чтобы внутренний оставлял эти 300 записей, а сверху делать like

Comment: @teran Ну сделать эту "вторую часть" подзапросом - источником основного запроса. Хотя сам вопрос, имхо, о том, "почему MySQL не догадался, что остальные условия оставят только 300 записей". С очевидным ответом ".. ну не шмогла ..."

Comment: @Akina дак да, вопрос именно об этом.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно

`where concat(id,startpoint,ic_txt,start_street,car_count,.....) LIKE concat('%',id,'%')`

строку из всех параметров в одну и в ней 1 раз полнотекстово искать. получите небольшой прирост в скорости.